# Setting CRS/SRID using the to_postgis function with GeoPandas?

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, geoalchemy-2, sqlalchemy

So, I'm trying to update a PostGIS table after doing some reverse geocoding and other column manipulation I'm running into the `find_srid() - could not find the corresponding SRID` error.

Based on my research, this should have to do with a [type-mismatch error](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/geopandas/geopandas/2095) with how the SRID is being passed and PostGIS expecting it as a varchar, but I can't seem to work out the right syntax to send the data to PostGIS.

I can confirm that the SRID is set in the geometry column in my database.

And here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import geoalchemy2
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry 
import shapely
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Point
import psycopg2
    
df = pd.read_csv('address-peng3.csv')
engine = create_engine('postgresql://Nizz0k@localhost:5432/Nizz0k')
df['geom'] = df['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)
crs = 'EPSG:4326'
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=df['geom'])
gdf.to_postgis('Peng', engine, if_exists='append', dtype={'geom': Geometry('POINT', srid=4326)})
```

UPDATE: So, per user @BERA's comments below, I've been able to progress through some of the errors and confirm that the GeoPandas data frame was created correctly. What I have noticed is that the SQL statement presented in the error: `SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'Peng', 'geometry');` fails if I run it in PGADMIN, but it fails because that does not correspond to the name of the geometry column in my database. Running the SQL `SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'Peng', 'geom');` returns the expected 4326.

UPDATE 2:
I found the following issue in the [GeoPandas Issue Tracker](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/geopandas/geopandas/2095) which seems to be related. In the cited link, the user has 'geography' columns and apparently there isn't an official way to target where the `to_postgis` function is looking for the SRID.

Comment: So, I have tried a few different ways to do it including using the crs = {init: 'epsg:4326'}, so I'm not sure which syntax is the right one as the few solutions I've seen don't seem to work.

Comment: it fails with and without, with I get an error about geometry being undefined, without I get the srid not found error

Comment: Are you sure gdf is a geodataframe, try `type(gdf)` after the gdf = ... line

Comment: could be the issue, doesn't return anything at all

Comment: Have you tried simply `gdf.to_postgis('Peng', engine, if_exists='append')` . You can then st_setsrid if your crs is unknown to postgis

Comment: So, I have tried it the way that you suggest (no luck). I think the issue I'm having per my update in the post is that to_postgis is looking for the SRID in a `geometry` col while my DB has a `geom` col. Apparently you can't specify and GeoPandas and to_postgis assume the column is called 'geometry'. I'm exploring trying to rename the column in the DB or using the to_sql method instead...

Comment: Just name it geometry then in `df['geometry'] = df['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)`

Comment: same SRID error with the sql statement looking for the SRID in the `geometry` column which doesn't exist in my db. Per the link Geopandas assumes the column is called geometry and doesn't give you a way to specify, so people with 'Geography' columns have to use the the `to_sql` method. I'll dig into your answer later today, since my quick switch over to the `to_sql` method produced a different error `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Point'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in a workaround you can import your **pandas** dataframe and create a point table like this:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile = r"C:\sample_data\data_1.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://youruser:yourpassword@localhost:5432/yourdatabase')
df.to_sql('data1', engine)
```

Then in postgresql:

```
--my geog column has wkt strings
select geog from public.data1 limit 1
--POINT (6688623.275372778 522577.4544667492)

--Add a geometry column
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','data1','geom',3006,'POINT',2); --3006 is my crs

--Fill with geometries using the wkt strings in geog column
update public.data1
set geom = st_geomfromtext(geog, 3006)
```

Comment: So, I don't want to just accept this without testing this, but going back to the first script you helped me with confirms your (deleted?) comments that I was creating the geodataframe either unnecessarily or incorrectly. I'm more than willing to give credit where it's due, but I don't want to lead someone astray that this problem is unsolvable because I'm a noob that doesn't know what he's doing. The only reason I separated the steps was that the geocoding for 1500 points is tediously long to wait for an error and move to the next step. Unfortunately, I haven't broken my questions to pieces...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your issue comes from the fact that you set a `pd.Series` in the `geometry` attribute of your `GeoDataFrame` instead of a string refering to the `geom` column name. When a `pd.Series` is set as `geometry`, `GeoPandas` considers it as a new specific column, while if a string is set the `geometry` column is just an alias for another one, thus when using the `to_postgis` method it is not considered as a column and not inserted into the DB.

Here is a complete example to reproduce and fix your issue (should be run with pytest). It creates a table with 2 objects and append two new ones in the test (we just update the IDs in this example but you could also update the geometries if you wish).

```
from pathlib import Path

from shapely import wkt
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import pytest

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from geoalchemy2 import Geometry


engine = create_engine("postgresql://gis:gis@localhost/gis", echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()


class Point(Base):
    __tablename__ = "point"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "gis"}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    geom = Column(Geometry(geometry_type="POINT", srid=4326))


@pytest.fixture
def meta():
    metadata.drop_all(checkfirst=True)
    metadata.create_all()
    yield metadata
    session.rollback()
    metadata.drop_all()


@pytest.fixture
def raw_data():
    return pd.DataFrame(
        [
            {"id": 1, "geom": "POINT(5 45)"},
            {"id": 2, "geom": "POINT(5.5 45.5)"},
        ]
    )


@pytest.fixture
def csv_points(raw_data, tmpdir):
    filepath = Path(tmpdir / "data.csv")
    if not filepath.exists():
        raw_data.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
    return filepath


@pytest.fixture
def db_points(meta, raw_data):
    pts = []
    for elem in raw_data.to_dict("records"):
        # Create point
        p = Point()
        p.id = elem["id"]
        p.geom = f"SRID=4326;{elem['geom']}"
        pts.append(p.id)

        # Insert point
        session.add(p)
        session.flush()
        session.commit()
        session.expire(p)

    yield pts


def test_to_postgis(csv_points, db_points):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_points)
    df["geom"] = df["geom"].apply(wkt.loads)
    df["id"] += 10
    crs = "EPSG:4326"
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry="geom")  # This works because the geometry column is just an alias to the geom column
    # gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=df["geom"])  # <= This fails because the geometry column is a Series
    gdf.to_postgis(
        "point",
        engine,
        schema="gis",
        if_exists="append",
        dtype={"geom": Geometry("POINT", srid=4326)},
    )
```